# Using Stokes Theorem to evaluate a line integral

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have been asked to evaluate the $\int{Fdr}$ over a curve $C$ where $F = yz\mathbf{i} + 2xz\mathbf{j} + e^{xy}\mathbf{k}$ and $C$ is the curve $x^2 + y^2 = 16, z =5$ with downward orientation

I want to use Stokes theorem, so I am thinking of parametrizing this surface as $(x, y, z)=(4 \cos t, 4\sin t,z)$ but I am confused as to what the bounds for $z$ would be since I have only been given $z =5$.  I know $t \in (0, 2 \pi)$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: There are no "bounds for z" because there is no integration with respect to z.  Replace z in the function by 5.  Integrate with respect to x and y.

Comment: @user247327 is the surface just a disk then?

Comment: @VinnyChase In fact, you can _choose_ a surface (with boundary $C$), but the disc would be the logical choice - see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Stokes to convert the line integral over $C$ to a surface integral, you need a surface with $C$ as the boundary. There are an infinite number of such surfaces but pick an easy one; e.g. the flat disc with boundary $C$.

A parametrization of the disc is:
$$\alpha(r,t) = \left( r\cos t, r\sin t, 5 \right) \quad\quad 0 \le r \le 4 \;, \; 0 \le t \le 2\pi$$
The normal on the surface is then given by $\alpha_r \times \alpha_t = (0,0,r)$ and $F(\alpha(r,t)) \cdot (\alpha_r \times \alpha_t)$ simplifies to $5r$, so the surface integral becomes an easy double integral:
$$\iint_S F \cdot dS = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^4 5r \, \mbox{d}r \, \mbox{d}t $$
Does that help? You can verify the result by also calculating the line integral directly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rough solution. It's been a while since I played with Stokes theorem. Hopefully that can help you nevertheless !
$$
\Sigma(r,\theta) = (r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,5) \hspace{2cm} 0 \leq r \leq 4,\ 0\leq \theta < 2\pi
$$
$$
\Sigma_r = (\cos\theta,\sin\theta,0) \\
\Sigma_\theta = (-r\sin\theta,r\cos\theta,0) \\
\Sigma_r \times \Sigma_\theta = (0,0,r)
$$
$$
\int_{\partial\Sigma} \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{l} = \iint_{\Sigma} rot\ \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{n} = \iint_{\Sigma} (x(e^{xy}-2),y-ye^{xy},z) \cdot d\vec{n} = \\
\int_0^4 dr \int_0^{2\pi} d\theta\ (x(e^{xy}-2),y-ye^{xy},z) \cdot (0,0,r) = \\
\int_0^4 dr \int_0^{2\pi} d\theta\ rz =\int_0^4 dr \int_0^{2\pi} d\theta\ 5r
$$